# how can i make database consistent in this situation?

Tags: mysql, database

I have problem while dealing with copy of database table entry from one file to other .

suppose i have two tables called one.sql , two.sql  , now i wana transfer some record from one.sql to the table two.sql, then delete that entry from one.sql ater copying success.

**problem :** suppose power was gone after i make copy from one to two, the delete record
 from one wasnt done , here in that case same record will be in both tables.               that i dont want. so in this situation how to handle these types of inconsistent  on fly.

Comment: Does this happen a lot?

Comment: @strawberry it will be a problem, if i cant delete that record from 1st table.. so how can i ensure that it will be deleted ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your RDBMS is *not* a simple datastore! It supports [journaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950246/mysql-transaction-journaling), [transaction isolation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html) and [atomic updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html). So...

... with transactional tables (*InnoDB*) and with decent isolation level simply do:

```
START TRANSACTION -- Or SET autocommit = 0
INSERT INTO two SELECT * FROM one WHERE ...;
DELETE FROM one WHERE ...;
COMMIT
```

[`COMMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) will *atomicity* apply the changes to the DB. That is, from the other transactions point of view, the move is either *done* or *not started*. No one can see it *half done*. Even in case of catastrophic failure (power outage).

Of course, if you move *all* your records, you could also rely on [`RENAME TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html)...

Comment: yes ur right , can u give me some more information about transaction isolation and atomic updates,  plz provide some usefull links for me to learn about these.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [transaction blocks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) to descrease unexpected results at some degree. But solving a power problem is another thing.

You can however use a batch and check if two tables don't contain same records at some interval, if you are worried about a power problem.

Comment: "But solving a power problem is another thing." That's simply *not* true. MySQL with transactional table (*InnoDB*) is [ACID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/glossary.html): That means that "either all the changes succeed when the transaction is committed, or all the changes are undone when the transaction is rolled back". "The database remains in a consistent state at all times". And "The results of transactions are durable: once a commit operation succeeds, the changes made by that transaction are safe from power failures, system crashes, [...]".